# Why when I want to access a TextView in the layout of the toolbar it turns null

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to access an element in the layout of the toolbar, but it turns null. **What do I need to do to access this TextView?**

And is it the right way to organize the toolbar in every class?

This is my main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.myapp.activity.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtToolbarTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="myapp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imbToolbarAdd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:src="@drawable/plus_circle"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_below="@id/appbar" />
```

This is where I want to access to TextView;

```
public class MyFragment extends BaseFragment {


public MyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cldirtanlar, container, false);

    setToolbar(view, "New Title", View.VISIBLE);

    return view;
}

public void setToolbar(View view, String title, int addButton) {
        TextView txtToolbarTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtToolbarTitle);
        txtToolbarTitle.setText("Kontlar");
        ImageButton imbToolbarAdd = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imbToolbarAdd);
        imbToolbarAdd.setVisibility(addButton);
}
```

}

Comment: Where does it return null? And did you confirm what is going on in your fragment lifecycle? And how that correlates to your Activity lifecycle.

Comment: txtToolbarTitle return null. And f I do not access an element in the class, the application works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `view.findViewById()`, which only returns views in your `R.layout.fragment_cldirtanlar`, not views set in your `MainActivity`.

You can instead use `getActivity().findViewById()` if you want to retrieve views created by your activity.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm.

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer if it answered your question. Best of luck!

Comment: Actually, yesterday I accepted it as the correct answer, but it remained as it gave me warning not to approve in such a short time. :) Thanks again.